# Variable vertical number of pages to print as PDF in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has a print area made up of two parts (see figure below).

[image]

The first, at the top, is fixed, and represents four print pages. Number four never changes. The second represents a column of pages that varies in quantity. In VBA's default print as PDF option, the entire indicated region is printed, both the fixed region, the variable region and the blank region. But I don't want the blank region.
I just want the blue and green region. I'm currently running the code:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                        OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
                        filename:=fname, _
                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Can anyone helps me?

Comment: Do a manual test first, Select all the Cells on P1-P4 and N1-N# that you want printed/PDF, and use the Print option of "Print Selection". If the outcome works, then work your VBA to Select those cells and use `ActiveSheet.Selection.PrintOut`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to *Ricardo A* I found the solution. I just select the desirable areas for printing through the code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:G35" & "," & "I1:K23" & "," & "O1:W33" & "," & "Y2:Y" & LastRow). _
                        ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                        OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
                        filename:=fname, _
                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```